# Install GParted 1.0

Tags: software-installation, gparted

What's the easiest way to install this brand new version of GParted?
There is a download link over here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted/gparted-1.0.0/gparted-1.0.0.tar.gz/download
But it seems to require compilation. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: How does it require compilation, it's an image you burn to flash drive and boot from it.

Comment: Nope. And be warned: the readme on your link says 1.0 but the download is the ISO for version 0.33 Seem dubious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download link you provided downloads the 0.33 version. I found [another source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-testing/1.0.0-beta1-2/gparted-live-1.0.0-beta1-2-amd64.iso/download) for 1.0.

> But it seems to require compilation. Is there an easier way to do it?

The download I link to is an ISO. So you burn it to a dvd/cd/usb. That is the more usual way since you need to unmount partitions you want to alter. And the root disk is mounted if you use an installed version.

If you want it as a direct installation the method where you need to compile it/install it from a tar.gz is the only method. There is no debian installer yet, nor a PPA on launchpad for this version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem with the link. I corrected my post with the link to gparted-1.0.0.tar.gz. That's what I was asking about, not the ISO. So you might want to edit your answer to reflect that.

Comment: The last sentence is the one you want: no there is no easier method (yet).

Comment: Indeed. But the readme file is pretty explicit, it even says how to download and install all the dependencies in one shot. Alas, after compiling and installing, GParted would not launch on my system. I have gained new respect for the official software repository...